# "ArrayRefOfHashrefs" subtype not working in Moose

Tags: perl, moose

So I have this little sketch, trying to get the hang of subtypes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
use Data::Dumper;

subtype 'ArrayRefOfHashrefs' => as 'ArrayRef[Hashref]';

has 'thingy' => ( 'is' => 'ro', 'isa' => 'ArrayRefOfHashrefs' );

package main;

my $foo = Foo->new('thingy' => [{ 'id' => 12 }]);

# The above produces: 


use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $foo->thingy;
```

And when I try to run it, I get:

> Attribute (thingy) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'ArrayRefOfHashrefs' with value ARRAY(0x7fda83028e08) at /[PATH]/site_perl/5.18.4/darwin2level/Moose/Object.pm line 24
>
> Moose::Object::new('Foo', 'thingy', 'ARRAY(0x7fda83028e08)') called at ../sketches/arrayrefofhashrefs.pl line 17

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer), which is very usefull if you work with objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo. The `Hashref` is called a `HashRef` with a capital **R**. The rest is fine.